# Storing collection of Polymorphic (via template specialization) objects

Tags: c#, polymorphism, template-specialization

I have the following problem. I have a generic class that has an abstract property which itself uses the generic argument:

```
abstract class Deserializer<T>
{
    T abstract Deserialize<T>(Node node);
}

class IntDeserializer:Deserializer<int>
{
    int override Deserialize(Node node){....}
}

class StringDeserializer:Deserializer<String>
{
    string override Deserialize(Node node){....}
}   


internal struct Command<T>
{    
    public IReadOnlyList<Component<T>> Components { get; }
    public Deserializer<T> Deserializer { get; }

    public Command(IEnumerable<Component<T>> components)
    {
        this.Deserializer = components.First().AsDeserailizer;
        this.Components = components.Skip(1).ToArray();
    }    
}
```

Imagine now I have a class that has methods which create `Command<T>`'s. I want to somehow store this `Deserializer` specialized field inside a data structure where I can retrieve later on and use the `Deserialize` method.

```
class A
{    
    List<something`>deserializers=new List<something>();

    string Method1()
    {
        ....
        Command<string> cmd;
        this.deserializers.Add(cmd.Deserializer);
        ....
    }

    int Method2()
    {
        Command<int> cmd;
        this.deserializers.Add(cmd.Deserializer);
        .....
    }    

....at some point i want to:

void Execute()
{
    string result=this.deserializers[0].Deserialize();
    int result2=this.deserializers[1].Deserialize();
}
```

Comment: so the above snippet doesn't work?

Comment: Well i do not know what the generic type of the LIST should be.I need to somehow get rid of the <T> or else it would be List<Deserializer<T>>

Comment: could you plz add all of your code? so i need to implement same

Comment: The simplest approach for your example would be `List<object> deserializers = new List<object>();` and then `string result = ((Deserializer<string>)this.deserializers[0]).Deserialize();`.

Comment: The `T` in the `Deserialize` method shadows the `T` parameter in the `Deserializer<T>` class definition. Does your real code have both?

Comment: I know but i somehow need to do it at runtime without casting.I was considering using `Expressions` but do not really know if i can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your `Deserialize()` method by using below code

Just make a list of `dynamic` or `object`

```
 class A
    {

        List<dynamic> deserializers = new List<dynamic>();

        //OR

        //List<object> deserializers = new List<object>();

        string Method1()
        {
            Command<string> cmd = new Command<string>();
            //var a = (T)Convert.ChangeType(cmd.Deserializer, typeof(T));
            this.deserializers.Add(cmd.Deserializer);
        }
        int Method2()
        {
            Command<int> cmd = new Command<int>();
            this.deserializers.Add(cmd.Deserializer);
        }

        void Execute()
        {
            string result = this.deserializers[0].Deserialize();
            int result2 = this.deserializers[1].Deserialize();
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

```
class A<T>
    {

        List<Deserializer<T>> deserializers = new List<Deserializer<T>>();

        string Method1()
        {
            Command<string> cmd = new Command<string>();
            var a = (Deserializer<T>)Convert.ChangeType(cmd.Deserializer, typeof(T));
            this.deserializers.Add(a);
            //return "";
        }
        int Method2()
        {
            Command<int> cmd = new Command<int>();
            var a = (Deserializer<T>)Convert.ChangeType(cmd.Deserializer, typeof(T));
            this.deserializers.Add(a);
            //return 0;
        }

        void Execute()
        {
            Node node1 = new Node();
            string result1 = (string)Convert.ChangeType(this.deserializers[0].Deserialize(node1), typeof(T));

            Node node2 = new Node();
            int result2 = (int)Convert.ChangeType(this.deserializers[1].Deserialize(node2), typeof(T));
        }
    }
```

Try once may it help you

Comment: Thank you very much .This is exactly what i needed !!! I completely forgot about dynamic.But still is there a way to do it with `System.Linq.Expressions`?Is there a way to bypass compile time?

Comment: @Bercovici Adrian, please view edited section in answer might be it help you :)

Comment: The use of `dynamic` was what i was looking for.Your first response was what i needed,since i have a `List` of deserializers and i do not want to use conditionals.

Comment: Your answer was the one that helped me thank you ,and i accepted it.

Comment: glad to hear that you have get rid from your problem :)